# Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to use angular-bootstrap but I keep getting error `Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Here is how I'm using it.

In my index.html I've included it

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
```

in app.js

```
angular
    .module('MyApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 
        'angularDjangoRegistrationAuthApp', 'http-auth-interceptor',
        'angularPayments', 'angularApp'])
```

in my controller

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('SubscriptionCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',
    'djangoAuth','LoginRequired','Validate','$location',
    function($scope, $rootScope, djangoAuth, LoginRequired, Validate, $location, $modal) {

        $scope.open = function(index) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
              animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
              templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
              controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
              size: size,
              resolve: {
                items: function () {
                  return $scope.items;
                }
              }
            });
```

HTML

Open me!

**Error**
When I click "Open me!" I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Comment: Typo!! You did not inject `$modal` @ `['$scope','$rootScope',
    'djangoAuth','LoginRequired','Validate','$location','$modal'`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to indicate that you need `$modal` as a dependency to your function:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('SubscriptionCtrl',
    ['$scope','$rootScope', 'djangoAuth', 'LoginRequired', 'Validate', '$location', '$modal',
    function($scope, $rootScope, djangoAuth, LoginRequired, Validate, $location, $modal) {
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer